# TCP/IP communication thread

Tags: java, tcp

I want to make a TCP/IP communication in Java but i want to open the TCP/IP port, send commands and then close that port.

I know i can open connection, send command, and then close connection in one method but the problem is: the machine i'm connecting to can't accept more that 5 connections and when the connection closes machine won't accept any other connection for about 6 seconds.

My goal is to open connection in one thread, send commands for some time and then after i'm finished i want to close connection.

This is how i'm doing it now:

```
void sendCommand(String command) throws IOException {
    String ipaddress = "192.168.0.2";
    Socket commandSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    BufferedWriter outToDetailFile = null;
    FileWriter fstream = null;



    commandSocket = new Socket(ipaddress, 7420);

    out = new PrintWriter(commandSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(commandSocket.getOutputStream()));
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(commandSocket.getInputStream()));


    out.write("c");out.flush();
    out.write(command);out.flush();

    String message = in.readLine();

    //System.out.println(message);

    out.close();
    in.close();
    commandSocket.close();

}
```

I basicaly need to split this method in 3 parts, one part which I call to open the connection, 2nd part to send commands (i need to send commands from my swing form) and then when i'm finished with sending commands i need to close connection on button click (or any other event).

The question is: How to send commands in already opened connection and then close that connection when i'm finished with sending commands.

I'm trying to achieve something like this

-Method openConnection should open connection.
-Method sendCommand should send (multiple commands at random time intervals (every 5-10 seconds)) connection to already opened socket (opened with method opneConnection)
-Method closeConnection should close connection that has ben opened by openConnection.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking for?!

Comment: The question is, how can I achieve this? 
How to send commands in already opened connection and then close that conneciton when i'm finished.

Comment: just pass connections as parameters to another function if you want to.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you show me on my example how to do it? I'm pretty much new to java and this thing is realy bugging me.

Comment: The problem is; you are already sending a command to an already opened connection and then closing the connection when finished.  BTW, You don't need to create `out` twice.

Comment: Also, there is no point using a buffered stream if you are going to flush everything you write.

Comment: Ok, i have updated my question again... 
I just realy don't know how to achieve this. If someone could split my existing method to 3 parts and show me how to do it it would save me

Answer (score 0):

### If you're asking how to refactor your code to have 3 methods here is how to do it :

```
Socket openConnection(String ipaddress) throws IOException {
    return new Socket(ipaddress, 7420);
}

void sendCommand(Socket commandSocket, String command) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    BufferedWriter outToDetailFile = null;
    FileWriter fstream = null;

    out = new PrintWriter(commandSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(commandSocket.getOutputStream()));
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(commandSocket.getInputStream()));

    out.write("c");out.flush();
    out.write(command);out.flush();

    String message = in.readLine();

    //System.out.println(message);
}

void closeConnection(Socket commandSocket) throws IOException {
    commandSocket.close();
}
```

Now you have to call the first method (`openConnection`) once when you load your form or when you want to send your first command.

Then for each command, call the second method (`sendCommand`), it will only send commands without closing the connection.

Finally, call the third method (`closeConnection`) when all the commands are sent (or when you close your form).

One important thing is not to close the input/output streams/writers as it could [close the socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream()).

*I just used your code without trying to correct or improve it, I think there will be some compilation failures (ex: declare the `out` variable twice).*

### If you're asking how to use efficiently your server with its limits (5 connections max, wait 6 minutes between additional connections) you can do this :

Use a **connection pool** ([Object pool pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern), [Connection pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool)).

The principle of a connection pool is that instead of asking a connection directly, you ask it to the pool that will create it (connect) for you and give it to you.
When you have finished with your connection (not anymore commands to send), you return it to the pool instead of closing it directly to make it available to other treads/consumers.

You may have to hand code the connection pool class by yourself with the limits you specified :

- 5 connection maximum
- if you close a connection, wait for 6 mins before reopening it

To optimize it and avoid the 6 min waiting limit, you could also try to reuse connections in a reasonable way.

Comment: An ExecutorService is a thread pool, it would make the example more complicated, but I don't see how it would help.

Comment: Maybe the ExecutorService is not the best example. But the principle of a connection pool could be a solution. He would 'simple' submit his commands to the pool and make the pool handle the limits (max 5 connections, reuse connection, wait for 6 seconds to reopen a new connection).

Answer (score 0):

why not create a ServerSocket on the receiving end, put it on an endless loop so its always listening, and open a thread for each new incoming connection.
you can now have endless connections.

if you need a code example just say so...

that's how I built my server/client application